# cURL_multi_exec Performance Issue?

Tags: php, performance, php-curl

I need to do 12 requests per second to the API on Twitch. I'm currently doing this with 3 processes, each doing 4 lookups per second but sequencially. I thought I'd give curl_multi a try so only 1 process would be needed.

Well - curl_multi is not quite what I expected !!! I thought all requests would be virtualy simultanious, but apparently not !

Currently, I am using file_get_contents (sequentially), and each request takes about 200-250ms, so one process could make about 5 requests per second maximum.

I thought that by using curl_multi I could do 12 requests simultaniously. Although it IS faster, it's not fast enough to do 12/sec. 12 lookups actually take approx 1.3 seconds. I used hrtime to measure the time taken between stages of the process, and it's this...........

```
do {
    curl_multi_exec($multihandle, $stillrunning);
    curl_multi_select($multihandle);
} while($stillrunning > 0);
```

that is taking all the time.

Apparently cURL can have performance issues and on reading various articles, it appears that cURL has issues with the OpenSSL 3 library, and that some people have rolled back to an earlier version which used OpenSSL 1.1 . This would obviously not be the ideal solution but then I don't even know if this would solve the problem anyway.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this please ?

System: Linux Zoe2 5.15.0-94-generic #104-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 15:25:40 UTC 2024 x86_64
PHP: Version 8.1.27
cURL: 7.81.0
SSL Version: OpenSSL/3.0.2

Comment: I don’t have an answer, but I’m curious if these 12 requests need to be aware of each other, and if this “12” will eventually scale. I ask because if there are 12 independent “things”, and that’s all it will ever be, I wonder if 12 dedicated processes might be a better solution, instead of worrying about synchronization and shared state?

Comment: @ChrisHaas - Well I have a system working with the 3 processes that works fine as it is, but it's 3 lots of logs to check per user. 10 Users atm = 30 processes and logs. If things get busy I may have 100 users = 300 processes and logs. That's why I wanted to reduce it to a single process per user.

Comment: You do realise you are also in the hands of the Other Site. If that cannot process all your requests at the speed you want then whatever you do at your end will not make a great deal of difference

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Yes. That is why there is a 12 per second limit. That is their published limitation per user.

Comment: I was reading more on this issue and ran a test using.............

```curl_setopt($multicurl[$instance], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);```

and it was 5 times faster 
This pretty much confirms what I read about OpenSSL 3 being slow. Anyone got a link how I can use an older OpenSSL version maybe ? I've been looking but can't find anything definitive.

Comment: On another server I have, it's running PHP 7.4 and is using OpenSSL 1.1.1 and the same script using cURL runs about 5 TIMES FASTER on that server. It gave me the idea to install that version of PHP on THIS server as well and try to get 7.4 to use OpenSSL 1.1.1. Problem is I now have the 7.4 installed but cannot find the page I found that gave an easy way to have both 1.1.1 and 3.0.2 installed at the same time. Any help would be appreciated.